# Rowcount in multiple select queries in stored procedure - T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Following Stored procedure doesn't return anything even if DB has matching record.Is the `Rowcount` is problem?
Anyone please help?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Usp_get_product_rates]
  -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
  @pcat1 CHAR(3),
  @pcat2 CHAR(3),
  @pcat3 CHAR(1)
AS
  BEGIN
      -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
      -- interfering with SELECT statements.
      SET NOCOUNT ON

      SELECT b.pcat1,
             b.pcat2,
             pcat3,
             rate1,
             rate2
      FROM   Product_Rates AS a
             JOIN Master_Rates AS b
               ON a.pon = b.pon
      WHERE  b.pcat1 = @pcat1
             AND b.pcat2 = @pcat2
             AND pcat3 = 'P'

      IF @@RowCount = 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT b.npa,
                   b.nxx,
                   blockid,
                   Inter_state_rate,
                   Intra_state_rate
            FROM   Rates_STF2 AS a
                   JOIN TPM AS b
                     ON a.pon = b.pon
            WHERE  b.pcat1 = @pcat1
                   AND b.pcat2 = @pcat2
                   AND pcat3 = '@pcat3'
        END
  END
```

Comment: I don't get why did you use the parameters correctly on your conditions on the first query and part of the second query, but decided to use `and  pcat3 = '@pcat3'` on your last filter

Comment: Also, you are adding `SET NOCOUNT ON`, and then want to use `@@ROWCOUNT` in your logic?

Comment: @Lamak - `NOCOUNT` doesn't interfere with `@@ROWCOUNT`

Comment: SET NOCOUNT ON has no effect on @@ROWCOUNT http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/12/02/sql-server-effect-of-set-no-count-on-rowcount/

Comment: so you want to return 2 resultset? or the first select is just for test if so see the Danielle's answer

Answer (score 1):

May be change this

```
pcat3 = '@pcat3'
```

to this

```
pcat3 = @pcat3
```

in your where clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do something like this:

```
If NOT Exists (select 1 from Product_Rates as a join Master_Rates as b on a.pon = b.pon where b.pcat1 = @pcat1 and b.pcat2 = @pcat2 and  pcat3 = 'P' )  
BEGIN
    select b.npa,b.nxx,blockid,Inter_state_rate,Intra_state_rate from Rates_STF2 as a join TPM
    as b on a.pon = b.pon  
    where b.pcat1 = @pcat1 and b.pcat2 = @pcat2 and  pcat3 = @pcat3
END
```